# Amaroks stops playing after one song

Tags: linux, debian, media, amarok

After upgrading amarok to 2.1 in Debian unstable last week, I noticed that it stops playing after the selected song. I have to click play to play the next one. The old version (1.4 something if I remember correctly) worked perfectly. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Have you looked at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=502363 ?

Comment: I have now, but unfortunately they don't really provide any fix :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed in Amarok Version 2.1.90 (its 2.2 rc1 I believe).